# Cypress Login with CSRF token

Tags: javascript, authentication, post, cypress, csrf-token

I would really like to expand on this topic ["Logging in with CSRF token"](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/blob/master/examples/logging-in__csrf-tokens/cypress/integration/logging-in-csrf-tokens-spec.js) as I have been banging my head against a wall for weeks now and I can't be the only one with this problem. All topics about logging in via POST or logging in with CSRF inevitably lead back to the above link.

Yet the recipes described in this link do not seem to work for me. They all assume that the CSRF token is created once you visit the Login page. But on our site, the CSRF token is only created once you login.

I tested with Postman and there is no CSRF token in the HTML or in the header before you are logged in.

I also tested it in Cypress with the following code:

```js
describe('gimme dat csrf token', () => {

    it('try to get the csrf token', () => {
        cy.visit(Cypress.env('url'))
        cy.getCookie('YII_CSRF_TOKEN')
            .then(async (c) => {
                cy.log(c.value)
                return c.value
            })

    })
})
```

This will return an error as there is no YII_CSRF_TOKEN

```
Type Error
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')
```

If I add a login step before, it will return the value of the CSRF token as expected:

```js
import {Login} from "../../pages/login/Login";

describe('gimme dat csrf token', () => {
    
   it('try to get csrf token', () => {
        cy.visit(Cypress.env('url'))
        login.loginCredentials(Cypress.env('userEmail'), Cypress.env('userPass')) //added login
        cy.getCookie('YII_CSRF_TOKEN')
            .then(async (c) => {
                cy.log(c.value)
                return c.value
            })

    })
})
```

Therefore strategies #1 (parse token from HTML) and #2 (parse token from response headers) from the above link can not work.

Recipe #3 is also not feasible as we have several live systems to test and we can't expose a /csrf route

This only leaves us with the strategy #4, which we have been using so far.

Any ideas or are we stuck with adding the "manual" login step to every single spec file?

Comment: What does this `cy.log(c.value)` print ? and can you try once removing `async` ?

Comment: When I remove the async from the 2nd code (the one that works) I get an error message: ```cy.then() failed because you are mixing up async and sync code.

In your callback function you invoked 1 or more cy commands but then returned a synchronous value.

Cypress commands are asynchronous and it doesn't make sense to queue cy commands and yet return a synchronous value.

You likely forgot to properly chain the cy commands using another cy.then().

The value you synchronously returned was: {{value of CSRF token)```

Comment: In the case without the login cy.log(c.value) returns an error as stated in OP: ```TypeError
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')``` regardless of the use of async

Comment: If you just execute this `cy.getCookie('YII_CSRF_TOKEN').then((c) => {
  cy.log(c.value)
})` do you get the cookie value ?

Comment: This also leads to ```TypeError
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')``` as there is no csrf token present at the moment

Comment: Are you sure the this is valid `YII_CSRF_TOKEN` ?

Comment: 100%. As I said when I login beforehand, this script returns the value of the csrf token

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think strategies #1 & #2 rely on the browser remembering credentials and supplying them to the login page, as happens with the Stackoverflow page - you don't have to log in every time you visit.

The main difference is you have used `cy.visit()` instead of `cy.request()` as shown in the recipes.

If you still are not able to successfully grab the token, try using your login with `cy.session()`. It will only call the login function once per session.

```js
/*
  Enable use of cy.session() and new behavior to handle caching 
  and restoring cookies, localStorage, and sessionStorage.
*/
Cypress.config('experimentalSessionSupport', true)

describe('...', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.session(() => {
      login.loginCredentials(Cypress.env('userEmail'), Cypress.env('userPass')) 
    })
  })

  it('try to get csrf token', () => {
    cy.getCookie('YII_CSRF_TOKEN')
      .then((c) => {
        cy.log(c.value)
      })
  })
})
```

Comment: And another useful function I was not aware of! Cy.session is extremely convenient!

Comment: As for remembering credentials: For security reason session Cookies are not saved in the app I am testing, so you have to log in every time you come back to the page. That explains why the recipes aren't working

Comment: Cy.session will be our default option now! Thanks a ton